# Sendmail errors from scheduled jobs

Tags: wordpress, scheduled-job, sendmail

I have been seeing some error messages in an email report from scheduled jobs. The messages are all:

/usr/sbin/sendmail: unexpected response 501 to RCPT TO command

which doesn't tell me a lot. It started about three weeks ago. My initial investigations suggested it might be the "update participants" job as they seemed to match (two each though, odd) the updates to "pending from waitlist" and this may have been used for the first time this month. But those emails have clearly got through OK as the individuals concerned completed a booking.

Yesterday, I got 12 instances of the message and nothing in the scheduled job log seemed to match. I can see nothing in the CiviCRM ConfigAndLog at this time. I don't have access to any system logs as I'm on a shared server. Any ideas how to proceed.

The site is CiviCRM 4.7.24 on WordPress 5.03 and using sendmail.